# I replace HTML using javascript, but that contains a form, want to keep value of that form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that I have a page I pull from the server every x seconds using some ajax, and then I replace some HTML on the site with the new HTML pulled from the server. The problem has always been that there is a form in that HTML. I want to know is there a way to preserve the value of the form (that the user has entered) when replacing the html in javascript.

Comment: also, there are multiple forms. Is there a way to detect all forms. They are all inside the replaced html, but if I add forms, I want the javascript to auto detect them. Maybe $('form') or something like that with a for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two callback functions (you should use $.ajax), in the callback before sending (beforeSend(x){ /*your code here*/; }) you save the parameters (to an array or hashtable): saved = $(element).val(); then in the second callback (use success(x){}) you write them back in. using $(element).val(saved);

Comment: I have 3 fields, would this work for all of them or how do I loop through them

Comment: also, there are multiple forms. Is there a way to detect all forms. They are all inside the replaced html, but if I add forms, I want the javascript to auto detect them. Maybe $('form') or something like that with a for loop

Comment: yes, $('form').find('input') will be an array of all your input fields.

Comment: you can loop through them using $.each or normal javascript arrays, or using .get(index).  Whatever you're happy with ;)

Comment: multiple forms: $('form') will be an array of all forms on the page.  $('form').get(0).find('input') will give you the array of inputs of the first form.  Find the length of $('form') to find how many forms you have, if you desire.

Comment: and how can I tell the difference between each input. Will they be in the same order every time the page updates

Comment: yes, they will be in the same order as long as the server provides them in the same order.  At this point its probably best if you stick some code on pastebin ;)

You can check for example name attribute ... $('input:name=email') will give you the element named email. Or get the element and get its attribute if you want to ask what it is.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit, too loop through its easiest to:
$('form').find('input').each( function(){ /*your code*/ } ); will execute your code on each input to the form/forms selected in turn.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var save = document.getElementById('userForm').value;
//replace HTML
document.getElementById('userForm').value = save;
```

Comment: I have 3 fields, would this work for all of them or how do I loop through them

Comment: also, there are multiple forms. Is there a way to detect all forms. They are all inside the replaced html, but if I add forms, I want the javascript to auto detect them. Maybe $('form') or something like that with a for loop

Comment: @macintosh264 - Yes, what you are suggesting will work. Why don't you try it and see? You don't need one variable per field, you can create an object and in your loop add a property to the object for each field.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways,

1. Send and then replace the value in the HTML on the server
2. Using JavaScript, save it in a session: http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/

I'd say the best solution would be to combine the two and save a session on the server, then load it each time you load the HTML.

-Sunjay03